# Why doesn't Angular automatically unsubscribe all active subscriptions, maybe on component destroy?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Or should it be RxJS that handles active subscriptions? Whoever, why doesn't it auto-unsubscribe all active subscriptions or at least provide a flag to auto-unsubscribe or unsubscribe all subscribers on component destroy or at some final event?

Comment: How would that work, exactly?

Comment: I am not sure why RxJs don't have such a mechanism even though it actually does exist in other implementations of Rx such as RxSwift like the `DisposeBag`. Would be an idea for a git repo actually.

Comment: But since this is really opinionated there is no real answer to your question.

Comment: Take a look this https://netbasal.com/automagically-unsubscribe-in-angular-4487e9853a88. It's a way to unsubscribe automatically, how? It's make a loop over all variables in the component and check the "observables". but what if you not create a variable? futhermore, some components are created and destroy several times (I imagine a simple component with a *ngIf). what is the reason to "penalty" this simples components? you has severals ways to unsubscribe automatically using takeWhile, e.g.

Comment: I am now mostly trying to use async as far as possible so that I dont need to worry about unsubscribing. Thanks for the suggestions !

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you as a developer to manage subscriptions. How you manage subscriptions is up to you and your team's discretion.

You can make unsubscribing *easier* by leveraging RxJS's operators and Angular's methods.

For example, we can have a component that extends `Unsubscribe` and implements `OnDestroy`.

```
export class AppComponent  extends Unsubscribe  implements OnDestroy{...}
```

The `Unsubscribe` class allows any component to have one subject to unsubscribe every Observable

```
class Unsubscribe {
  public readonly destroy = new Subject<void>()


  protected destroySubs() {
    this.destroy.next()
  }
}
```

Any subscription we have, (that is not in our template) will use the [`takeUntil` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) to keep a subscription alive until the component is destroyed

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  extends Unsubscribe  implements OnDestroy{
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  someSubscription: Subscription

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.someSubscription = interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(console.log)

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ngOnDestroy()
    }, 5000)
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroySubs()
  }
}
```

Here is a code example. Try running this in chrome and watch what happens in the console: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unsbscribe-ex?file=src/app/app.component.ts